# scala pattern matching guard condition with or expression (or more preciesly - scala boolean | vs ||)

Tags: scala

I have the following example:

```
val i:Option[Int] = Some(3)

val q = i match {
  case Some(n) if n == 2 | n == 3 => 42
  case Some(n) => n
  case None => 12
}
```

It seems that the following which is identical except for the "or" in the guard which is `||` instead of `|` produces an identical result.

```
val q = i match {
  case Some(n) if n == 2 || n == 3 => 42
  case Some(n) => n
  case None => 12
}
```

What then is the difference between `|` and `||` in the guard position? If there is a difference then which one should be used?

Comment: The difference is that `||` is short-circuiting. If the first operand is true, then the second operand will not be evaluated. The `|` operator will always evaluate both operands.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pattern matching. It's simply bit-wise vs. boolean logic.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Not within an `if` statement.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Ahhh, you're right. :X

Comment: Thanks all, I was not aware that you could use the "bitwise" operators on booleans. I guess it makes some sense. Regardless, when you know not what to look for you can't find it. That being the case I will rename the question once more so that people that stumble down the path same as I can find the wrongness of their assumptions quicker.